# Word spacing differences between either MacTeX, microtype or setspace versions

Tags: spacing, mactex, microtype, setspace

I'm migrating to a new notebook (which means a complete **MacTeX** update) and noticed word spacing differences when compiling a paper I'm currently working on. I would like to keep the old word spacing since it looks better, especially in the printed version; and since the new word spacing adds 2-3 pages.

What is under my suspicion is the interplay between microtype and setspace, however this is not certain (and the versions are identical). I copied the Fonts collection from the old to the new computer.

Are there any known word spacing problems of the packages in the MWE below? What could be the problem?

**TeXLive-2013 64, microtype v2.2 (mt-cmr.cfg Computer Modern Roman) & 2.5a, setspace v6.7a**

[image: Old version]

**TeXLive-2015 64, microtype v2.2  (mt-cmr.cfg Computer Modern Roman) & 2.5a, setspace v6.7a**

*e.g. the first lorem paragraph takes more lines*

[image: New version]

**MWE**

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, parskip=half*]{scrbook}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying that you're running version 2.2 _and_ 2.5a of `microtype`?

Comment: I get your second example, with the following versions: scrbook -- 3.18; setspace -- 6.7a; geometry -- 5.6; babel -- 3.9m; lipsum -- 1.3; microtype -- 2.5a; mt-cmr.cfg -- 2.2. Can't (easily) test TL2013.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised: `microtype` changed, `pdftex` changed, …

Comment: @Sverre: It's from a log entry mt-cmr.cfg: `File: mt-cmr.cfg 2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman`. Thought it would be better to include it since I was suspecting microtype.

Comment: @egreg: Alright, any advice what one could do? Or can I only revert to an old version of one of the packages?

Comment: I can reproduce this.

Comment: @egreg The version numbers of `microtype` are identical. If you comment out `setspace`, you get the same output for 2013 and 2015. Even though `setspace` hasn't changed. ?? Same for `microtype`.  Can't reproduce with `book`, though.

Comment: Isn't this really to do with changes to KOMA? You are trying to obliterate KOMA's effect, it is true, using `geometry` and not following the manual's recommendations with respect to `setspace`. But, even so, KOMA has changed a lot. For example, removing the `parskip` option, which you'd have to expect to conflict with `setspace` somewhat, gets the same output for 2013 and 2015, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help - merely removing `parskip` from the `documentclass` options completely reproduces my former document. There is indeed a double definition in the MWE with `setspace`, but I don't see their influence on the bad word spacing I saw before. (Would be good to know the actual problem, but I'm pretty glad that the former state of the document can be recovered..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Koma-Script option `parskip=half*` executes

```
\setparsizes
  {0pt}% \parindent
  {.5\baselineskip plus .5\baselineskip}% \parskip
  {.25\linewidth plus 1fil}% \parfillskip
```

and this didn't change between TeX Live 2013 and 2015. However, something else changed. If I ask `\showthe\parfillskip` after `\begin{document}`, I get

```
106.69783pt plus 1.0fil
```

when `setspace` is not loaded, but an incredible

```
2047.99998pt plus 1.0fil
```

when `setspace` is loaded (together with several `Overfull \hbox` messages, of course).

If I compile with TeX Live 2013, I get the same value as before when `setspace` is not loaded and

```
104.56389pt plus 1.0fil
```

when loaded.

It's quite difficult to say where the bug is. But you can overcome it by doing

```
\usepackage{setspace} % no option

\AtBeginDocument{\onehalfspacing}
```

This might not give exactly the same result as TL 2013, because the natural width of `\parfillskip` will be slightly larger (about 2pt, the values are shown before).